# PySide export XML ElementTree from menu - having problems

Tags: python, xml, pyqt5, pyside, qfile

So, it's not an XML question but a PySide/Menu item. I have a little XML viewer/editor for simple xml files and I want to save resulting xml files. I have included a code snippet here with functionality removed for brevity. The focus I have here is just the menu 'save' function as this is the last thing I seem to be stuck with.

I have commented out the hard 'save' link. The hard link works for writing files. If I bypass the QtCore.QFile(filePath) return from the QFile dialog and replace the file path with a hard link, the xlm tree exports as expected.

When I use the dialog menu (this is the problem), the os file is opened but nothing is ever written and file size remains as '0' size. Is this a file locking problem maybe? Can't see why the two should not both work and the 'open' side of things (commented out for brevity) works just fine in building and viewing my xml tree.

Anyone can help me? It must be soooo obvious but maybe I have been staring at it too long and the problem is straight in front of my eyes!

Thanks,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# using python3

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse, Element


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.fileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&File")
        self.fileMenu.addAction("&Open...", self.openFile, "Ctrl+O")
        self.fileMenu.addAction("&Save...", self.saveFile, "Ctrl+S")
        self.fileMenu.addAction("E&xit", self.close, "Ctrl+Q")

        #self.xmlPath = ""
        self.view = QtGui.QTreeView(self)
        # snippet - edit/view code removed here for brevity

        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
        self.setWindowTitle("XML Editor")

        self.xmlPath = ""
        self.fileIn = ""
        self.fileOut = ""


    def openFile(self):
        filePath,_ = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File",
                self.xmlPath, "XML files (*.xml);;HTML files (*.html);;"
                "SVG files (*.svg);;User Interface files (*.ui)")

        if filePath:
            self.f = QtCore.QFile(filePath)
            print("Open filePath")
            print(self.f.fileName())
            self.fileIn = self.f.fileName()
            #doc = parse(self.fileIn)
            #root = doc.getroot()
            print("fileIn")
            print(self.fileIn)
            self.f.close()


    def saveFile(self):
        fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,
                "Save Project File", QtCore.QDir.currentPath(),
                "XML Files (*.xml)")[0]

        if not fileName:
            return

        self.outFile = QtCore.QFile(fileName)
        print("Save outFile")
        self.fileOut = self.outFile.fileName()
        print(self.fileOut)

        doc = parse("catalog.xml")
        root = doc.getroot()

        # setting filename via dialog - uncomment for (working) hardcoded name variable
        doc.write(self.fileOut, xml_declaration=True)

        # but hardcoded name works fine function
        #doc.write("catalog_saved.xml", xml_declaration=True)

        if not self.outFile.open(QtCore.QFile.WriteOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text):
            QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, "XML Editor",
                    "Cannot write file %s:\n%s." % (fileName, outFile.errorString()))
            return


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here is the test xml file catalog.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?>
<CATALOG>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1982</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
  </CD>
  </CATALOG>
```

** **Update:** Actually solved it myself now by using this function instead of the above Save function:

```
def browseClicked(self):
    name = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File')
    self.browseEdit.setText(name[0])
    doc = parse("catalog.xml")
    root = doc.getroot()
    doc.write(name[0], xml_declaration=True)
```

It's basically the same function but separated and this time I declared the filename as a QLineEdit field instead of a string at the initialisation. So maybe I have a string object or initialisation problem though the original was returning a string path and does work with a hardcoded filename path. Still trying to figure why my original one didn't work. I hate not understanding things.

Comment: You need to open the file *before* attempting to write to it.

Comment: How do you mean in this example? I have it working in a separate button in a widget using variable "name = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File')" and it works (setting doc.write() to QFileDialog name). It seems like the same thing I am doing in the button except this is not a widget and called from MainWindow menu item. Do I maybe need rewrite this into setup a separate function and setup a signal connection?

Comment: so, actually solved it by swapping out the save function above for this :            def browseClicked(self):
        name = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File')
        self.browseEdit.setText(name[0])
        doc = parse("catalog.xml")
        root = doc.getroot()
        doc.write(name[0], xml_declaration=True)                                            Basically declared a QLineEdit and set it with the function but all works fine. Still, I hate not understanding things so I am still interested as to why the original function didn't save. Strange.

Comment: I already explained why. Calling `doc.write()` before `outFile.open()` simply makes no sense. If you open a file for writing, it will immediately truncate it. Why do you even create a `QFile` in that context, given that you don't ever actually write anything to it? A file-name is just a string, not a file-handle.